Problem with Bluetooth running the server on Linux and the client on Windows using BlueZ and C++ : error 10051
I am running the server software on Linux Ubuntu with the following code:
  int serverSocket, clientSocket;
  struct sockaddr_rc serverAddr = {0}, clientAddr={0};

  socklen_t clientAddrSize = sizeof(sockaddr_rc);

  // Create Bluetooth socket
  serverSocket=socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);
  if (serverSocket<0)
  {
    perror("socket creation failed: ");
    return false;
  }
  bdaddr_t  bdaddr_any={{0,0,0,0,0,0}};

// Bind the socket to any local Bluetooth adapter
  serverAddr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
  serverAddr.rc_bdaddr = bdaddr_any; // bind to any local Bluetooth adapter
  serverAddr.rc_channel = 20;

  if (bind(serverSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr,sizeof(serverAddr))<0)
  {
    perror("Bind failed");
    close(serverSocket);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // listen for incoming connections
  if (listen(serverSocket,1) <0)
  {
    perror("Listen failed");
    close(serverSocket);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  };
  wxPrintf("Listening bluetooth\n");

  while (true)
  {
    wxPrintf("Waiting for incoming Bluetooth connections...\n");

    // Accept incoming connection
    clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &clientAddr,&clientAddrSize);
    if (clientSocket<0)
    {
      perror("accept failed");
      continue;
    }


I am running the client software on Windows 10 with the following code:
    // Create a Bluetooth socket
  m_serverSocket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);
  SOCKADDR_BTH serverAddr = { 0 };
  if (m_serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    IB_P_APP->IbLogOutputMessageAdd("Failed to create socket: error %d", WSAGetLastError());
    return false;
  }

  // Set the address of the remote Bluetooth device to connect to
  serverAddr.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
  serverAddr.btAddr = *reinterpret_cast<BTH_ADDR*>(&m_Server.Address.ullLong); // this is the addres found by function BluetoothFindFirstDevice()
  serverAddr.serviceClassId = RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID;
  serverAddr.port = 20; // Replace with the RFCOMM channel number to use

  // Connect to the remote Bluetooth device
  if (connect(m_serverSocket, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&serverAddr), sizeof(serverAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    IB_P_APP->IbLogOutputMessageAdd("Failed to connect to %s: error %d", m_bt_devices[index].szName, WSAGetLastError());
    return false;
  }
 type here

The server is listening on port 25 while the client tries to connect on the same port.
The client first searches for the server, finds it and uses the server's address to connect.
The connection on the client then fails with error code 10051 (or sometimes 10060)
Running the same server software on a Windows 10 runs fine, client connecting to the server.
On Linux there is no firewall installed, using bluetoothclt I see it is registered and pairable.
The bluetooth dongle is plugged into a USB port ands seen as USB2.0-BT.
I have tried different ports without success.
Any help is highly appreciated!
Best regards,
Peter
I ported the server code to Windows and this worked fine, so both client and server running on a Windows platform.
I reprogrammed it to ethernet communication and this also works fine.

Seems to be a persistent problem - the failure of this C code under bluez. The official solution is to use DBus to access bluez - very difficult if starting from scratch with DBus.
There is a non-bluez solution in this C and Python library.
https://github.com/petzval/btferret
This is code for a classic server. It advertises a serial RFCOMM connection on channel 1. If prompted for a PIN, enter 0000 on both devices. Set line feed (10) as the line end marker on the client.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "btlib.h"

int callback(int node,unsigned char *data,int len);

int main()
  { 
  if(init_blue("devices.txt") == 0)
    return(0);
  
  classic_server(ANY_DEVICE,callback,10,KEY_ON | PASSKEY_LOCAL);
  close_all();
  }
  
  
int callback(int node,unsigned char *data,int len)
  {
  printf("Received: %s",data);
  write_node(node,"OK\n",3);  // reply
  if(data[0] == 'x')          // send x to exit server
    return(SERVER_EXIT);
  return(SERVER_CONTINUE);
  }




I have read connecting from a Windows bluetooth client program to a Linux  bluetooth server program using DBus can't be done due to platform differences.
I still find it strange using normal sockets and the bluez library on Linux does not work.
I thought sockets were universal so to avoid problems.

Yes, I agree. This question in various forms has come up multiple times in the last few years. I have never seen an answer that specifies a problem in the code and a fix. It seems we have to conclude that this code, which used to work under bluez, just doesn't any more. I cannot see why a server running from DBus will not work - DBus is just an over-complicated way of implementing the same underlying Bluetooth functions. There should be a DBus/Bluetooth library somewhere that does this if you want to go the official route.

I've done some more testing with my code. It seems  bluetooth is working well with code above in the following circumstances :
windows -> windows
linux -> linux
linux -> windows
The only thing that doesn't work is:
windows -> linux
I still wonder if the problem lies in the Bluez library.
I had a look at the btferret library. This only works when having administrative rights, running the code with sudo. Reason for is is probably the use of RAW_SOCKET.
